# What is the difference between man and --help?

Tags: man, documentation

I used both command lines and displayed the same output

Comment: Another answer is hinted at here: [discrepancy between path for binary and man page](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/281621/80216). When you say *`foo `* `--help`, you're running the actual *`foo`* program, and getting documentation that's written into that program. But if you say `man ` *`foo`*, you might be getting documentation for a different version of *`foo`*.

Answer (score 2):

Some programs and commands implement `--help` to give a quick usage summary but `man` pages are usually much more detailed, better formatted and allow navigation through them instead of a plain text output.