# discrepancy between path for binary and man page

Tags: path, man

Systems often have multiple versions of binaries and the one selected depends on the priority in `$PATH`. For instance, the system I am using has a couple version of sort:

```
$ which sort
~/coreutils-8.25/bin/sort
$ ~/coreutils-8.25/bin/sort --version | head -n 1
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.25
$ /bin/sort --version | head -n 1
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.4
```

On the system I am using, the version from GNU coreutils 8.25 is selected by an invocation of `sort` because of its precedence in `PATH`. However, the `MANPATH` environment variable on the system has been established such that the man page for the `sort` from GNU coreutils 8.4 is displayed (i.e., for `/bin/sort`, which is not the binary having precedence).

A three-part question arises from this scenario.

First, is there a simple way to instruct `man` (or the shell) to use or produce a form of `MANPATH` that reflects `PATH`, or must one do this manually (i.e., by finding the paths to the man pages that are associated with each entry in `PATH` and then concatenating these man paths in the same order as `PATH`, an exercise that would have to be repeated any time a change is made to `PATH`)? Were there a mechanism to establish concordance between `PATH` and `MANPATH`, then the expected man page would be displayed automatically, avoiding the problem of inadvertently reading a man page for a version other than the one used by default.

Second, is there a command that allows one to quickly determine the path of the default man page (e.g., something akin to `which "man sort"`, which would report the path of the man page that is displayed when executing `man sort`). For instance, when I type `man sort`, I have no indication of the specific file on the system that is being delivered to the pager.

Third, is there a way to obtain the man page for an explicit version of a command (something like `man ~/coreutils-8.25/bin/sort` in my case for the GNU coreutils 8.25 version of sort, rather than having to track down the associated file, which in my case can be found to be ~/coreutils-8.25/share/man/man1/sort.1 or ~/coreutils-8.25/man/sort.1).

Comment: You appear to have a local installation of `coreutils`. Why? It's generally a bad idea to have local installs unless really necessary, and in this case, I don't see the necessity.

Comment: @FaheemMitha : I am using a cluster and don't want to use the provided version of coreutils, which I am unable to change. So I have put another version in my home directory for personal use.

Comment: If @FaheemMitha hadn't commented that, I would have suggested that you report it to your distribution's support as it simply reflects a bad installation.  You should find a way to address the problems properly.  Having multiple versions of the same software is a good way of getting weird problems for nothing.

Comment: what's so bad about coreutils 8.4 that you have to have a local install of version 8.25?  wouldn't it be better to just write your scripts etc so that they used the system version of coreutils?

Comment: @cas : I want the `--parallel` option for `sort`

Comment: @JuliePelletier : I agree. Unfortunately the cluster is used by thousands of individuals and I wouldn't be able to effect a change of core system binaries, hence my installation of a parallel set of utilities.

Answer (score 1):

For *local* installs such as that, I use a shell-script to setup the `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `MANPATH` values so that I get consistent results.  Without a prop like that, you will *not* get automatic consistent results.

Here is an old example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# $Id: with-ncurses,v 1.1 2006/09/02 23:04:39 tom Exp $
export LIBS="-lncursesw"
for prefix in \
        /usr/local/ncurses6
do
        test  -f $prefix/lib/libncursesw.so && break
        test  -f $prefix/lib/libncursesw.a  && break
done

if [ -d $prefix/include/ncursesw ] ; then
        export CPPFLAGS="-I$prefix/include/ncursesw $CPPFLAGS"
        if [ $prefix != /usr ] ; then
                export CPPFLAGS="-I$prefix/include $CPPFLAGS"
        fi
fi

if [ $prefix != /usr ] ; then
        export PATH=`newpath -bd $prefix/bin`
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`newpath -n LD_LIBRARY_PATH -bd $prefix/lib`
        export LIBS="-L$prefix/lib $LIBS"
        # this doesn't work for db30:
        # export LIBS="-static -L$prefix/lib $LIBS -shared"
fi

case `partition` in
rh*|md*)
        export MANPATH=$prefix/man:`manpath`
        ;;
*)
        export MANPATH=$prefix/man:`manpath -q`
        ;;
esac
eval $*
```

Making scripts like that *portable* is a problem, since there are no standards for the way `MANPATH` is used.  But you can adapt things like that for specific systems.

The script, by the way, uses [`newpath`](http://invisible-island.net/misc_tools/index.html#item:newpath) to modify those variables and avoid duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning LD_LIBRARY_PATH and providing your script, which I will try to adapt to my system.

Answer (score 1):

2. You almost have it. 
`man -w sort` shows you **w**here it gets the man page for `sort`.

1 & 3. Probably not, since man pages can be anywhere.
3. You can do a brute-force search:

```
find / -name "sort.1*"
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `man -w`. That's exactly what I wanted for #2. I was worried that what you said about 1 & 3 would be true. I also used `find` to find the man pages for the relevant version of `sort`.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`:

```
export MANPATH="$HOME/coreutils-8.25/share/man:$(manpath)"
```

This will put your man page tree in $MANPATH first, before the default MANPATH (as supplied by the `manpath` command)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you put your man pages next to your executables (i.e. executables in `/somewhere/bin`, man pages in `/somewhere/man/manSECTION`), and you're using a man implementation with a [`manpath`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=manpath) command, such as most Linux systems and FreeBSD and OS X, just run `manpath`. It constructs a `MANPATH` variable that's parallel to your `PATH.

```
unset MANPATH
MANPATH=$(manpath)
```